# Priority queues "simulation" with python

Tags: python, priority-queue

This is supposed to be simulating the priority queue, but apparently it's not working...

```
class PriorityQueue:

  def __init__(self):
      self.elements = []

  def add(self, element):
    """
    This will add the element to the correct location in the list. 
    Example: If given a list where the priorities are thus: 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5

    And you add 5, it will go here:
        1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5
                            here^

    """
    for i in range(0,len(self.elements)):
      if element[0] <= self.elements[i][0] and element[1] <= self.elements[i][1]:
        self.elements.insert(i,element)
```

Comment: How is it supposed to work and what does it actually do? Can you show an example of use? What are the two parts of each element?

Comment: "apparently it's not working" How did you reach that conclusion? How are you testing it? What error message do you get? What outcome and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: I suspect you're expecting `self.elements` to be an ordered list. Python's priority queue is implemented using a binary heap, which is not a fully ordered structure.  See the "Implementation" section of the [Wikipedia article about heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) for details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the class you need:

I wrote the class and below it is a testing code
I supposed the element is a tuple where the 0th position is the priority, you can make it a list or my favorite as a dictionary

```
import random

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []
        
    def add_element(self, new_element):
        if len(self.elements) == 0:
            self.elements.append(new_element)
            return
        for index, element in enumerate(self.elements):
            if index == 0 and new_element[0] <= element[0]:
                self.elements.insert(0, new_element)
                return
            
            elif element == self.elements[-1]:
                self.elements.append(new_element)
                return
            
            elif new_element[0] > element[0] and new_element[0] <= self.elements[index + 1][0]:
                self.elements.insert(index + 1, new_element)
                return
                                          
test_elements = []

with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    names = [line.strip().title() for line in f.readlines()]

for i in range(20):
    test_elements.append((random.randint(1,5), names[i]))
    
queue1 = PriorityQueue()
for elm in test_elements:
    queue1.add_element(elm)

for elm in queue1.elements:
    print(elm)
```